# Does inexistence exist?

Tags: ontology, existence

If inexistence exists then how is it inexistence?
And if inexistence does not exist then how come it into existence and we know about it?
Or is it paradox?

Comment: Everything that exists exists. And what does not exist does not exist.

Comment: Some progress can be made (maybe) with the ontology of non-existent *objects*. See [Alexius Meinong](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meinong/).

Comment: The first question seems to be a category error.  Paintedness (the state of being painted) cannot itself be painted, and yet it is all about being painted, and there is no deep problem with that notion.  So there is no prima facie reason why nonexistence should be nonexistent just because it is *about* not existing.

Comment: Inexistence is better phrased as non- existence. But since the prefix 'in' means not, the two words are synonymous. Existence and non- existence are used in ontology (study of being) to separate the real or non-created things from the non-existent or things which originate from a proximate cause. And yes the linguistic usage is confusing and takes time to understand clearly.  All of what was just described involves only the primary or basic tenets of ontology (in metaphysics). At an advanced stage the non-existent are termed 'puncta', flashes which barely exist if at all; less than contingent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already the question about the existence of existence is based on a delicate linguistic expression:

Primarily single objects exist. Everybody understands a sentence like: There exist people from Norway. But already the question, whether abstract concepts exist, and if yes, in which sense they exist, is debated. E.g., in which sense exist "humanity" or in which sense exist mathematical objects?

I consider existence and non-existence an abstract concept, namely a property of possible objects. Then one can deal with the question of the existence of these two properties in alike fashion.

Of course this approach does not answer the original question. But as stated above, the question has no generally accepted answer. For more information cf. the philosophical terms *nominalism* versus *realism*.

Answer (score 0):

Inexistence does not exist. Once we die, we don't stop existing. We are eternal spirits. We have a premortal, a mortal, and a post-mortal life. Our bodies may decompose, but our eternal spirits will forever stay alive.